# Jquery: How can i track changes in input elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to track changes on an input element but this should be done whenever anything change its value, not only users typing.

The keyup event is not what i need as already specified and the change event only works when the input loses focus.

Any ideas of how can i do this?

Comment: When you say *"whenever anything change its value"* are you talking about the value being changed via some other javascript code?

Comment: Yes, via javascript code and user input ( keypress and browser autocomplete ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you not just bind handlers for the "change", "paste", and "cut" events, as well as "keypress" or "keyup"?

Answer (score 6):

In non-IE browsers, you can handle the `input` event.
In IE, you can handle the `propertychange` event.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/nt4SD/) (works in all browsers)

Comment: +1 what is the difference between `change` and `propertychange`. `change` does work in IE last I checked??

Comment: I tried this solution but it does not work when user uses his browser autocomplete. In this case the change in input is simply ignored.

Comment: @JohnO: They're two different events.  See the documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: `change` fires when the value of an input field changes - still don't see why you need propertychange as he is only changing the value, not any other attributes.

Comment: @JohnO: `change` doesn't fire often enough.

Comment: i'm not even sure what that means? change has fired whenever i've needed it to.

Comment: @JohnO: It doesn't fire as you type.

Comment: For IE9: add the `keyup` event to the demo code to also capture backspace, delete and cut (ctrl-x). Not necessary for chrome.